# Most pythonic way to search through text to find answers to questions

Tags: python, regex

For example lets say I have this text.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla
>   condimentum aliquam felis a efficitur. Nunc vulputate, risus quis
>   mollis tristique, odio velit tempus urna, quis tincidunt nulla nunc
>   sit amet justo. Maecenas quis quam molestie, hendrerit augue et,
>
> 1. What is your name and occupation?
>
> I am Jerry and I'm unemployed
>
> 2. How big is your family?
>
> There's five of us
>
> Etiam ipsum lorem, ullamcorper nec massa id, vulputate gravida sem.
>   Duis pulvinar lacinia mattis. Aenean dictum quam sed tincidunt
>   eleifend. Suspendisse convallis in leo at accumsan. In viverra odio
>   non ex egestas, malesuada feugiat justo malesuada. Curabitur vitae

What would be the easiest way to search through the text, and find the answesr to the questions? Could a regex that grabs all text between question marks and the next number work? Cheers.

EDIT: Does this regex make sense in the slightest? `\\?([^]]+)\\[0-9]`

Comment: *"Could a regex that grabs all text between question marks and the next number work?"* Depends on the content. If you are sure that your answer won't contain any number, then it will work else Not

Comment: @anonymous I didn't even think of that, it is possible there will be numbers inbetween. What about just checking if there is any text at all between questions? An indicator to if the person has answered

Comment: Based on the content you pasted, it looks like all your questions starts with tab i.e `\t`. content between two tabs will be your question answer text. So, your answer will be everything after `?`. Even though answer may also have `?`, but there will be very less probability of that

Comment: Unless your usecase is very limited/constrained, you should consider using a cognitive text analysis service. DIY is non-trivial.

Comment: Well, what's generic? The question starts at linestart with a number followed by a dot and ends with a question mark on the same line. Followed by at least one newline, followed by one line to extract (starting with a word character) not ending in a whitespace. You can [play with it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ysNsGT/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the question will always be like (or similar to) the current format as you've shown then using the following pattern could potentially work:

```
^.+\?$|(.*)
```

The pattern finds all the questions, then captures everything else into a group. It might require a bit of tweaking to get it to capture exactly what you want, but this might be a good starting point.

```
import re

regex = r"^.+\?$|(.*)"

result = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    for match in result:  
        print(match)
```

**Example:**

https://regex101.com/r/bweMiZ/2